# how to create a coupon in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Am currently working with coupon in the backend when i create the coupon and give an expiry date to it and change the date in my database it still shows valid.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'discount' => 'required',
            'validity' => 'required',
        ]);

        Coupon::insert([
            'name' => strtoupper($request->name),
            'discount' => $request->discount,
            'validity' => $request->validity,
            'created_at'=> Carbon::now(),
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('coupons');
    }
```

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach($coupons as $coupon)
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{$coupon->id}}</th>
          <td>{{$coupon->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$coupon->discount}}</td>
          <td>{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($coupon->validity)->format('D, d F Y')}}</td>
          <td>
              @if($coupon->validity >= Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))
              <span class="badge text-bg-primary">Valid</span>
                 @else
                 <span class="badge text-bg-danger">Invalid</span>
             @endif
          </td>
           <td>
             <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
             <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
           </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
```

Comment: What is the date you're getting for validity?

Comment: When you call `Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')` you're getting a string; if you've [set up your model correctly](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) `$coupon->validity` should be a Carbon date. You can't compare those two things. You can compare two Carbon dates though: `@if ($coupon->validity >= now())`

Answer (score 3):

try with this

```
@if(Carbon\Carbon::parse($coupon->validity)->gt(Carbon\Carbon::now())
```

I recommend putting this logic inside a getter in your Coupon model. Make sure you cast your validity field to DateTime.

In your model, it should look like this

```
class Coupon extends Model {
    
    protected $casts = [
        'validity' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
    public function getIsValidAttribute()
    {
        return $this->validity->gt(now());
    }
}
```

And on your blade view you can use it like this

```
@if($coupon->is_valid)
```

Good luck